# 5e d&d Attempting to make a bag of holding

Tags: dnd-5e

Ok. I feel really stupid for asking this but I've been trying to find out how to make a bag of holding for one of my characters and I can't find anything referencing how characters NPC or otherwise would make them nor find a spell that would work.

Answer (score 2):

Rules for PCs crafting magic items can be found on page 128-129 of the DMG.